Generalization bound with covering number
I would like to bound generalization error using covering number.
For the problem I’m working on, the hypothesis class is bounded and covering number is finite. Also, I have already know the covering number. I would like to use the covering number to bound generalization error.
Are there any methods of help?
Thanks.
